# How to globally define a counter in jinja2 so that it will remember its last value

Tags: python, counter, jinja2

Here is my code. I want that after the ending of the `for` loop the count should remember its last value so that i can check whether it entered in the `if` clause under `for` or not. But here it is not remembering the last value and all the time print `"no coupons available"` along with the coupons even if it find coupons.

So what is the solution to do so??

```
{% set count = 1 %}
{% for x in coupon_codes %}
    {% if x[2]=="example.com" %}
        <tr>
        <td><code>{{ x[0] }}</code></td>
        <td>{{ x[1] }}</td>
        {% set count = count + 1 %}
        </tr>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
{% if count==1 %}
<b>{% print "No Coupons Available." %}</b>
{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [filtered `for`](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/dev/templates/#for) feature of Jinja2:

```
{% for x in coupon_codes if x[2]=="example.com" %}
<tr>
    <td><code>{{ x[0] }}</code></td>
    <td>{{ x[1] }}</td>
</tr>
{% else %}
<b>No Coupons Available.</b>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thanks but there is a little typo : The last line should be `{% endfor %}`

Comment: Ah, yes. Fixed now! Thanks for the heads up.